# How can I save two files with the same name inside the same folder, without renaming any using php?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I save two files with the same file name in the same folder without renaming anyone using php?
For instance: A user has an audio file name "first.mp3"; and another user uploads another file named: "first.mp3"; and I want to save these two files without renaming any so that when people are downloading the audio from the front end, the name does not change.
I can do this by concatenating a random number to differentiate the files but I want to beat this method of renaming.

Should I be saving each file inside a unique folder and save the file names to database?  but this method will create too many folders which i don't think it is appropriate.

Comment: What if one user uploads two files with the same name?

Comment: Be it the same user or another user, I don't want files to be renamed

Comment: To answer the question as asked: You cannot do this. What you've specifically asked for is not possible. Your multiple folders solution is one possible correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two files with the same name in the same folder.
You would either have to add a random string to the end of each file like you suggest or save each user's files in a directory allocated to their account.

Regards,
Leslie

Answer (score 0):

Saving multiple files with the same name within the same folder is just not possible.

I'd opt for a strategy that would involve saving the original filename somewhere (in a database, for example) along with the name/path of the actual file. When the User downloads the file (presumably through a web app of some sorts), you can set the name of the file via headers with your language of choice.

You could even rename the files to something completely random when they're uploaded so you can have them all in one folder - as long as you store the original filename somewhere, you can always set it before you serve it back to the end user.